# IIS ARR reverse proxy only works for existing resource URLs

Tags: .net, url, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have URL Rewrite & ARR installed in my IIS:
[IIS machine dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzxYQ.png)

And ARR proxy enabled:
[Server proxy setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf9fZ.png)

I have a .net app in my IIS.
[a local .net app site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUUoI.png)

There are 2 files in it. WebForm1.aspx and WebForm2.aspx
[.net project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQu7J.png)

And if I set up URL Rewrite from webform1.aspx to an external website, it works
[URL Rewrite rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB0Ck.png)
[browser log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ulLF.png)

But if I set it up with webform3.aspx, it shows 404. It's like the rule doesn't take effect for non-existing page.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyUmn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we enable failed request tracing then we will notice that the rewrite rule has succeeded.

[image]

Then problem is asp.net pipeline brake it.

[image]

If you try it on an empty website, it will work.

[image]

So you'd better be careful when you reverse proxy to an external website.

Comment: So I guess the `stopProcessing="true"` does not stop asp.net pipeline from braking it?

Comment: stopprocess flag just stop processing further rules inside url rewrite module. It won' effect the event outside URL rewrite module

Comment: I know this is old, but I don't quite understand about it working with an empty website? How do I make it work with an empty website, and not return 404?